# Will a positive semidefinite matrix $A$ become positive definite if a positive real value is added to one of its diagonal entries?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $A$ that is irreducible, and with algebraic and geometric multiplicity for $\lambda(A) = 0$ as $1$. Another matrix $B$ with one entry in a diagonal is positive and all other zero, i.e., $B = {\rm diag}([0\, 0\, 0\, 1])$. Show that $A+B$ is a positive definite matrix.

In other words, will positive semidefinite matrix and irreducible $A$ become positive definite if a positive real value is added to one of its diagonal entries?

Comment: Diagonalising the matrix $A$ seems a good starting point.

Comment: For $A=B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0\\ 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$ the conclusion fails

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I would add irreducibility to the matrix as well. I will change my question a bit.

Comment: When checking with $2 \times 2$ Matrix $[ [(A) B] [B (C)] ]$ giving $[ [(A+D) B] [B (C)] ]$ & $[ [(A) B] [B (C+D)] ]$ , we see that the Eventual Polynomial we get is "Original Polynomial + $Dx^2$" & "Original Polynomial + $Dy^2$" which might be $0$ when that variable is $0$. Hence , when $D$ is Positive , PSD Matrix will remain PSD Matrix , PD Matrix will remain PD Matrix. That will be lost when $D$ is Negative. We can generalize it to $n \times n$ Matrix too , where we will "increase" the Polynomial by $Dz^2$ , which might be $0$ when that variable is $0$. PSD Matrix will not give PD Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 &1&1\\1&1&1\\
1&1&1\end{pmatrix} \quad B= \begin{pmatrix}1 &0&0\\0&0&0\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}  $$ Then $\ker A$ is one dimensional and $A+B$ is not positive definite, as its determinant vanishes.